# What is the origin of the names of I and tt?

Tags: coq

The Coq standard library has two unit type. One `True` is typed in `Prop`, and has a single constructor `I : True`. The other `unit` is typed in `Set`, and has a single constructor `tt : unit`. I wonder what is the origin of the names of `I` and `tt`.

Comment: tt could stand for Term Tree

Comment: @GonenI Do you have any references to back up your version?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Its my best guess after reading "Given a term t, its corresponding term tree Tt" in Definition 4, "Proof-Pattern Search in Coq"  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0081.pdf

Comment: @GonenI I'm sorry, but there is no connection between Definition 4 and `unit` type.

Comment: `tt` / `ff` appear in a few early papers about the lambda calculus, for example: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/Lambda_Definability.pdf

I would say that if you dig a bit in the literature about Church-enconding in type theory you would find that `tt` was the lambda function used to encode the single inhabitant of the `unit` type.